# Does Darktable manage the files of a collection?

Tags: photo-management

I am currently trying out Darktable.
Coming from Digikam I am confused about several things, the most prominent for me being:

**Does Darktable manage my files on disk?**

In Digikam, I define a collection folder where all my files will be stored and then when I import Images from a Camera, folder, SDcard, $whatever it will copy them over to my collection and apply different operation like EXIF renaming in the process.
Afterwards I can be sure to find all my files in the collection folder in the format I wanted.

So, does Darktable do that, too?
To me it has more of a look that it *just* manages files I import without everr eally touching them.
If so, what are my options for organizing the disk/folder/file part of my collection?
Relying only on Darktables collection mechanisms for organizing my collection seems like a "vendor lock in" to me in that it makes migrating to a different product later on way harder than if all metadata is stored in the actual image files and the files are neatly sorted in folder and such.

Answer (score 2):

**[No](http://www.darktable.org/faq/)**

Darktable only offers image manipulation and tagging operations, file management must be done in other applications